# Need help displaying array content programmatically

Tags: php, function, jquery, arrays

I have an associative array that contains key pairs for the titles of a jQuery navigation list that is working for the

portion of the code. See left side of the picture below:

[image: tabbed content area]

The problem is on the right side. The list on the right is automatically populating, when it should be the content for the tab "Appalachian & Rural Studies". When I load the page, this is generated, but when I click any of the individual links, the code works correctly and only displays the content area heading associated to the correct tab, see below:

[image: Imgur]

Here is the code doing all of this:

```
<!-- Tabbed research areas content -->
<h4>Research Areas</h4>
<hr></hr>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs li").click(function() {
    //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
    $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');

    //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
    $(this).addClass("active");

    //  Hide all tab content
    $(".tab_content").hide();

    //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
    var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    //  Show the selected tab content
    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

    //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
    return false;
});
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
<div id="tabs_wrapper">
            <div id="tabs_container">
            <?php 
                $Researchareas = array(
                     '1' => 'Appalachian & Rural Studies',
                     '2' => 'Child Welfare',
                     '3' => 'Gerontology',
                     '4' => 'Human Trafficking',
                     '5' => 'International Social Work',
                     '5' => 'Intimate Partner Violence',
                     '7' => 'LGBTQ',
                     '8' => 'Substance Abuse and Misuse',
                     '9' => 'Suicide Survivors and Bereavement',
                     '10' => 'Trauma and Post-Traumatic Stress',
                     '11' => 'Veterans and Military Social Work'
                );
                ?>
                <ul id="tabs">
                <?php 
                    foreach ($Researchareas as $key => $value){
                        $tabname = 'tab'.$key; 
                ?>
                    <li><a href="#<?php echo $tabname ?>"><?php echo $value ?></a></li> 
                <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs_content_container">
                <?php
                foreach ($Researchareas as $key => $value) {
                    $divtab = 'tab'.$key;
            ?>
        <div id="<?php _e($divtab); ?>" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
        <h4><?php _e($value); ?></h4>
            </div>  
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!--end tabbed research content area-->
```

I essentially just need the  to not load all of the array values in a complete list on page load, and instead, just display the first tab accurately, like in the second image. I'm not sure where I'm missing something, but I most definitely am. Any help is greatly appreciated and I will be forever thankful.

Comment: You may need CSS To hide all the `.tab_content` divs so that none show up on the initial load. Then jquery will display them once a tab is clicked.

Comment: Recommend reposting at main StackOverflow site.  Likely to be closed as off-topic on WPSE.